# How can i get record with must match minimum given ids with SQL IN?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-clause, sql-in

I have tables:

users:

```
id | name
1  | first name
2  | second name
3  | third name
4  | fourth name
```

projects:

```
id | name
1  | first
2  | second
```

projectInvitees:

```
id | userId | projectId
1  | 1      |     1
2  | 2      |     1
3  | 2      |     2
4  | 3      |     1
```

I want a record like:
the project which must has minimum both assignee userId with 1 and userId with 2

I tried:

> select projectId from projectInvitees where userId IN (1, 2);

but it returns projectId 1 and 2, because I user IN but as I mention I want the only projectId 1

Can any one guide me with this

Comment: `select projectId from projectInvitees where userId IN (1, 2) GROUP BY projectId ORDER BY COUNT(*) LIMIT 1;`?

Comment: What is asignee?

Answer (score 0):

This variant may help you. For change need users count just change parameter in `HAVING` statement.

```sql
    SELECT projectid
    FROM projectinvitees
    WHERE userId IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY projectid 
    HAVING count (*) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT distinct projectId 
FROM projectInvitees
WHERE userId IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY projectId
HAVING count(*)  = 2;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [Kazoku]> SELECT * from projectInvitees;
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | userId | projectId |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 |      1 |         1 |
|  2 |      2 |         1 |
|  3 |      2 |         2 |
|  4 |      3 |         1 |
+----+--------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [Kazoku]> select distinct projectId 
    -> from projectInvitees
    -> WHERE userId IN (1, 2)
    -> GROUP BY projectId
    -> HAVING count(*)  = 2;
+-----------+
| projectId |
+-----------+
|         1 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [Kazoku]>
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT
    min(projectid) projectid
FROM
    projectinvitees
WHERE
    userid IN (
        1,
        2
    );
```